# Android Q: Get image from gallery and process it

Tags: android, android-10.0, storage-access-framework, scoped-storage

I know it seems like a very basic question, but it's specifically for Android Q.

I just want to get an image from Gallery and compress it and send to the server. But because of the Android Q's Scoped Storage, it's harder than I thought. I'll first explain what I did with code:

First I send out the intent to pick the image.

```
fun openGallery(fragment: Fragment){
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
    intent.type = "*/*"
    val mimeTypes = arrayOf("image/*")
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes)
    fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_PICK)
}
```

It works fine, and I'm able to get the image in the onActivityResult method

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_PICK && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        val selectedImage = data.data

        val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(activity!!.contentResolver, selectedImage)
        val bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
        mBinding.circularProfileImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
    }
}
```

Okay now the question is how can I access this image in File format, so I can further process/compress it.

Following things I've tried:

```
val mImagePath = getImagePathFromUri(activity!!, selectedImage)
```

This is the path I've got:

```
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20191022_152437.jpg
```

I created a file from it, in the following way:

```
val file = File(mImagePath)
```

And Following is my custom logic to compress and upload image:

```
val mNewFile = MediaCompressor.compressCapturedImage(activity!!, file, "ProfilePictures")
uploadProfile(mNewFile)
```

In this custom logic, I have a method to handle sampling and rotation of the image as follows:

```
fun handleSamplingAndRotationBitmap(context: Context, selectedImage: File, reqWidth: Int, reqHeight: Int): Bitmap {

    val mUri = Uri.fromFile(selectedImage)

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true
    var imageStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(mUri)
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options)
    imageStream!!.close()

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize =
        calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight)

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false
    imageStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(mUri)

    var img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options)

    img = rotateImageIfRequired(context, img!!, mUri)
    return img
}
```

But when I'm trying to open the stream using **context.contentResolver.openInputStream** 
I get the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20191022_152437.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I know I'm getting this because in Android 10 we don't have the permission to directly access files from external storage.

So, please help me figure this out, how can I use the image from external storage as a file in Android 10.

Note: I've all the required permissions, so that's not the issue

Comment: `now the question is how can I access this image in File format, so I can further process/compress it.` You will not even try to get a path in File format. There is no need as you can do all processing by opening an inputstream on the obtained uri.

Comment: getContextResolver().openInputStream(data.data);

Comment: Thank you, @blackapps. It's working.

Comment: What if the image is a video and all I wanted was to stream it with a third party video player like before? I used to stream videos with the default android video player by just passing file.

Comment: Can you share working code ? @ParagPawar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Following things I've tried:

There is no possible reliable `getImagePathFromUri()` implementation.

> In this custom logic, I have a method to handle sampling and rotation of the image as follows:

You do not need a `File` in that function. After all, *your very first statement in that function* goes and creates a `Uri` from that `File`. So, replace the `File` parameter with the `Uri` that you have, and skip the `Uri.fromFile()` call.

> how can I use the image from external storage as a file in Android 10.

You can't. And, as demonstrated above, you do not need it for what you are doing.

If you find yourself in some situation where you are stuck using some library or API that absolutely positively *must* have a `File`:

- Open an `InputStream` on the content, using `contentResolver.openInputStream()`, as you are doing today
- Copy the bytes from that `InputStream` to some `FileOutputStream` on a file that you can read/write (e.g., `getCacheDir()` on `Context`)
- Use your copy with the library or API that requires a `File`

Comment: Yes, It's working, such a silly mistake. Thank you very much, also thank you for those extra pointers.

Comment: Just one more question, will this work on Android below 10? Or do I have to write an alternate solution for the same using old APIs?

Comment: @ParagPawar: I am not certain what "this" refers to. As I noted, `getImagePathFromUri()` is not reliable in general. And I do not know much about `MediaCompressor`. But your `handleSamplingAndRotationBitmap()` function is not tied to Android 10, if that is what you are asking. Note that the places where you have `!!` are code smells -- those functions legitimately can return `null`, and you should handle those scenarios gracefully.

Comment: "Copy the bytes from that InputStream to some FileOutputStream on a file that you can read/write (e.g., getCacheDir() on Context)"

I used to stream videos to video players using file urls/path. so now I will need to copy an entire video to my directory before I can use the same method?

Comment: @TatiOverflow: Most video players should be able to support a `content` `Uri`. So, hand them a `Uri` that you get from the `MediaStore` (using `ContentUris.withAppendedId()`, the `Uri` of the `MediaStore` collection, and the `_ID` of the piece of media).

Comment: I am using Unity Video Player, I get content:// protocol is not supported. 

Protocol "content" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Comment: @TatiOverflow: Apparently, Unity Video Player is designed for Web sources, if it uses `libcurl`. You may need to reconsider your use of Unity Video Player if you wish to play on-device content.

Comment: Damn. I worked for Android devices -28 until now. Then I guess I am going to have to do it the hard way. copy video contents to cache directory. This will of course bloat the storage. But I guess it's the only option.

Comment: does it work when target sdk is 30 and running on android 11?

Comment: @FaiqMustaqeem: I am uncertain what "it" refers to in "does it work". If you are referring to my recommendations at the bottom of the answer, then yes, it works.

Comment: @CommonsWare, yes i was referring to these recommendations at bottom of your answer.
Open an InputStream on the content, using contentResolver.openInputStream(), as you are doing today

Copy the bytes from that InputStream to some FileOutputStream on a file that you can read/write (e.g., getCacheDir() on Context)
Use your copy with the library or API that requires a File

Comment: @FaiqMustaqeem: Yes, that technique will work on all versions of Android that support `FileProvider` (API Level 15 and higher IIRC). The downside is the time and storage space needed for the copy.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Directory for data to be stored in Android/data/package name by:

```
private void createDir() {
    String timeStamp = utils.currentTimeStamp();
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(null);
    File image;
    try {
        image = File.createTempFile(timeStamp, ".png", storageDir);
        Log.i("SANJAY ", "createDir: " + image.getPath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("SANJAY ", "createDir: " + e.getMessage());

    }
}
```

now call the gallery intent:

```
 intent = new Intent();
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
 intent.setType("image/*");

 startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```

In onActivityResult():

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 100) {
           Uri mediaUri = data.getData();
            
            //display the image
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getBaseContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(mediaUri);
                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                bind.photo.setImageBitmap(bm);
                //Log.i("SANJAY ", "onActivityResult: " + saveBitMap(this, bm));
                uri = Uri.fromFile(saveBitMap(this, bm));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } 
    }
}
```

the get the Uri from File using this method:

```
private File saveBitMap(Context context, Bitmap Final_bitmap) {
    File pictureFileDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/Android/data/"
            + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
            + "/"/*Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), ""*/);
    if (!pictureFileDir.exists()) {
        boolean isDirectoryCreated = pictureFileDir.mkdirs();
        if (!isDirectoryCreated)
            Log.i("SANJAY ", "Can't create directory to save the image");
        return null;
    }
    String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
    File pictureFile = new File(filename);
    try {
        pictureFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream oStream = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        Final_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 18, oStream);
        oStream.flush();
        oStream.close();
        Log.i("SANJAY ", "saveBitMap :: Save Image Successfully..");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("SANJAY", "There was an issue saving the image.");
        Log.i("SANJAY", "Error :: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return pictureFile;
}
```

Comment: so, you are saying that intent call for opening gallery remains same for newer versions??