# android Q display picture

Tags: android

this is what I did :

```
Intent showPhotoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        showPhotoIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("content:" + getItem(position).getAbsolutePath()), "image/*");
    } else {
        showPhotoIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:" + getItem(position).getAbsolutePath()), "image/*");

    }
```

only on andorid Q a application is not display a photo. I do not know what I do wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you have added this line of codes for permission to use in Android Q :

```
<application
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
...
</application>
```

and also it is not helping then you go to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58540374/12837534)

Comment: Yes I added this but it does not help me

Comment: are you able to get the uri of image ? like `content://`

Comment: I will check this

Comment: I get content/storage/emulated/0/Android/data.com.test.photo/files/Pictures/photo.jpg

Comment: In my application I see a thumbnail but I want to see on full screen I do not see a picture

Comment: what do you want means to pick an image from gallery ?

Comment: No I take a picture on camera in my app and save it in to my folder next I display a photo in ListView and i see this picture  and when i click on picture I want to display apicture on whole screen . And I call my function which i put in my question . I do not see a photo only on android Q

Comment: `I take a picture on camera in my app`. That is something different from ACTION_VIEW. And you did it in such a way that you got a thumbnail. Yes that is possible.