# Set default image gallery on kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, image-gallery

I am trying to implement gallery functionality in kotlin with android studio using default component. The goal is to click a button and open the desired path as a common Intent .
I can't understand how it is possible that the emulator only opens recent images for me instead of the path I specified on the file provider.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nRtC.png)
The part of code that I'm using is :

```
 fun dispatcherGalleryImage(){
    try {

        val uri: Uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(requireActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString().replace("/storage/emulated/0", "")).path.toString())
        Log.info(uri.toString())
        val intent=Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        intent.type ="image/*"
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_GALLERY_IMAGE)
    }catch (ex: Exception){
        Log.info(ex.toString())
    }
}
```

Comment: You may need to add `intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)` as shown in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66166309/12053756

Answer (score 0):

> I can't understand how it is possible that the emulator only opens recent images for me instead of the path I specified on the file provider

First, you are not using `uri`, except to log its value.

Second, the string that you are passing to `Uri.parse()` is not a valid string representation of a `Uri` (use `Uri.fromFile()` for a `File`).

Third, you are not using `FileProvider`. And a `file:///` `Uri` is largely useless on Android 7.0+, as it will trigger a `FileUriExposedException` if you pass it in an `Intent`.

Fourth, `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` does not take a `Uri` as input. It is unclear why you are using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` when you already have the content.

If your objective is to let the user view the image in their desired image viewer, use `ACTION_VIEW`, and put the `FileProvider`-supplied `Uri` and concrete (non-wildcard) MIME type in the `Intent`.

Comment: Thanks in advance for the comment.
I'll explain what my main problem is. Basically I would like to open the android gallery in a specific path which in this case coincides with the path of the fileprovider. Could you kindly tell me how I could do without going through the recent images?
Thanks again

Comment: @mpilz91: There are hundreds of gallery apps, spread across tens of thousands of device models and ~3 billion devices. None have to offer a means by which you can tell the gallery to not view an image, but rather view some collection that the image happens to be in. There is no standard `Intent` structure for that action. It is possible that some specific gallery apps support something like that, but not all.